# How to prevent QT library project generating so, so.1 so.1.0 etc…

Tags: c++, qt, build

I have my library project and when build it it creates so, so.1 so.1.0 so.1.0.0 files (on windows)
It is annoying I would like to have only .so
I bet it is some sort of qmake setting, I just cannot figure out what is it.
Building for QNX, QT 5.3.1, QT Creator 3.1.2

Here is my pro file, it super simple:

```
# The name of the library
TARGET = mylib

# Compile a .so, not a binary
TEMPLATE = lib

# Libraries we need
LIBS += -L"$${FRAMEWORK_BUILD_LIBS}" -lqcore

# QT libraries we need
QT += core

HEADERS += \
mylib.h

SOURCES += \
mylib.cpp
```

I was suggested to use
CONFIG += plugin

Any possible implication when using option, and if there is any alternatives, because I don't really feel like adding this option (CONFIG += plugin) in commercial project, seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: Hi, Don't know if you know why you have all of these files but it's just an easiest way to manage versioning of your libs. For a commercial project I advise you to keep producing these files. Anyway, don't know your goal but I don't know if it's possible too :x But I don't think adding CONFIG += plugin is a bit of hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post-build script, which will delete generated `.so.1` files.

Here is example how to add post-build scripts for qmake: [How to add custom targets in a qmake generated Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776476/how-to-add-custom-targets-in-a-qmake-generated-makefile)